# Use excel input with 2007 poi stream ,do not release excel resources?

Tags: pentaho, kettle

Excel input (select 2007 poi stream) ,after some steps , I want to move some excel files (previous excel input use it) to another directory, then I have an error, the excel file I want to move is using by another one.  It is not release resources?

Comment: are you writing and moving the same file ?? or by anychance you have opened the file !!.. can you give more details to this?

Comment: @Rishu yes,i'm sure. and do not opened the  file anywhere.you can just do it like below;  first, create a transformation, add a excel input step, select 2007  poi stream ,and select a file suffixed  with  xlsx, then do  something. second ,create a job,add a transformation step,use transformation file you created before,after this step  , add a move file step,then select the file you use before ,move this file somewhere. try it.  thanks